# How to pythonically get the max of a numpy argwhere function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use numpy argwhere to find where a maximum in my data is. Below is a sample set that describes what I am doing:

```
bins = np.arange(10)
data = np.array([[6],[4],[8],[5]])
np.argwhere(bins<data)

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [0, 5],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

What I want from this data is

```
array([[0,5],
       [1,3],
       [2,7],
       [3,4]])
```

This could be done with a for loop, but I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this.

EDIT:

What I have now done was use Pandas and groupby. I am still wondering if this is the best method.

```
t = pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(bins<data))
time = t.groupby(0)
time.max()

   1
0   
0  5
1  3
2  7
3  4
```

Now that I have this, I have a new problem. Lets say I have another set of data:

```
BigData = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]])
```

How can I use the array I achieved

```
array([[0,5],
       [1,3],
       [2,7],
       [3,4]])
```

To be put in this new data to get BigData average up to the index in the second column. I.E

```
(0+1+2+3+4) / 5
(0+1+2) / 3
(0+1+2+3+4+5+6) / 7
(0+1+2+3) / 4
```

would be the return of BigData, assuming that we got the index value of where this happens in column two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly short Numpy solution that's also pretty fast:

```
A = np.argwhere(bins<data)
print A[np.r_[A[1:,0] != A[:-1,0], True]]
```

Comment: On my machine,%timeit A[np.r_[A[1:,0] != A[:-1,0], True]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 µs per loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy solution. It is not as readable as the Pandas version, but timing suggests it is much faster:

```
>>> arr = np.argwhere(bins<data)
>>> arr[np.where(np.diff(np.vstack((arr, [arr[-1][0]+1, arr[-1][1]])), axis=0)[:,0] > 0)[0]]
array([[0, 5],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 4]])
>>> %timeit arr[np.where(np.diff(np.vstack((arr, [arr[-1][0]+1, arr[-1][1]])), axis=0)[:,0] > 0)[0]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.7 µs per loop
>>> %%timeit
... t = pd.DataFrame(arr)
... time = t.groupby(0)
... time.max()
... 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be pretty fast for me, taking advantage of `argmax` working left -> right:

```
>>> bins[::-1][(bins[::-1] < data).argmax(axis=1)]
array([5, 3, 7, 4])
```

For me %timeit shows that this takes around 11µs.

However, manipulating the array to have the index as the first column (as follows) increases time to around 25µs:

```
>>> np.column_stack(
... [np.arange(data.shape[0]), bins[::-1][(bins[::-1] < data).argmax(axis=1)]])
array([[0, 5],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Fastest and most readable. Could you read the newest edit and see if you could help me with that as well?

Comment: @NightHallow If you've new question then please post a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: On my machine, %timeit A[np.r_[A[1:,0] != A[:-1,0], True]] -> 10000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 µs per loop, while %timeit np.column_stack([np.arange(data.shape[0]), bins[::-1][(bins[::-1] < data).argmax(axis=1)]]) -> 10000 loops, best of 3: 25.9 µs per loop.