# Find the average using an array of indexes

Tags: python, numpy, average

If I have the following data

```
In [203]: data
Out[203]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [206]: index
Out[206]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 4]])
```

How can I use index to find the average of data. The average should be taken over the row, up to and including the index, i.e

```
In [209]: data[index[0, 0], :index[0, 1]+1]
Out[209]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [210]: np.mean(bd[index[0, 0], :index[0, 1]+1])
Out[210]: 1.0
```

And the end result should be

```
1.0
0.0
3.5
2.0
```

[The index was achieved using these methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758813/how-to-pythonically-get-the-max-of-a-numpy-argwhere-function/24760765) Essentially, I have

```
In [223]: bins
Out[223]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])

In [224]: height
Out[224]: 
array([[ 6],
       [ 2],
       [15],
       [10]])
```

and I need to take the average of the `data` only where `bins` is less than `height`.The shape of `data` is in `(len(height), len(bins)` which in this case is `(4,10)`

Comment: so you already have a working solution? Im confused as to what the question is... @TheSoundDefense it looks like he posted alot of code ... Im assuming thats what he tried

Comment: See the answer that I posted. Thats what I want, to take the index and find the average of data, I just included the extra stuff in cause index could be done differently to better serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice explicit way to achieve this is using Numpy’s masked array functionality as follows:

```
>>> data
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> index
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 4]])
>>> data_ma = np.ma.array(data, mask = np.arange(data.shape[1]) > index[:, 1, None]) 
>>> np.array(data_ma.mean(axis=1))
array([ 1. ,  0. ,  3.5,  2. ])
```